# Been through verification process but cannot seem to add the Developer Add (to create a new app)

Tags: facebook, accessibility

I hope someone can help. I have registered for a developer account and have verified my mobile number and card details. But every time I go into http://developers.facebook.com/apps (as i intend to to create a new app) it takes me back to my Facebook page. Even if I select it from search box, it does not seem to come with a 'request for permission' 
What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the app with your personal user - not your pages user.